# facing issue for resValue and buildConfigFields when i change AGP version to 7.1.3 from 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin-7

Below is my code snippet.

afterEvaluate {
applicationVariants.all { variant ->

```
        variant.getPreBuildProvider().configure() {
            it.doFirst {
                resValue "string", "app_name", "API33Demo"
            }
            it.doLast {
                buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_DEMO_APP", "true"
                buildConfigField "String", "IS_ODYSSEY", "\"YES\""
                buildConfigField "int", "VARIANT_ID", "1"
            }
        }

    }


}
```

If i use AGP 4.0.1 then same code working perfectly. Issue is coming when i update AGP to 7.1.3.

Really appreciate if anyone help me on above issue.